# Goutte can't click link

Tags: php, string, string-comparison, goutte

I am not sure what is going on here, I am using Goutte for crawling, trying to crawl all the exploits on exploitdb, but apparently I am not able to click 1 specific link. Here is the code:

```
<?php

    require_once 'goutte.phar';

     use Goutte\Client;

     $client = new Client();

function crawler_metasploit(){


          global $client;


          $crawler = $client->request('GET','https://www.exploit-db.com/search/?order_by=date&order=desc&pg=1&action=search');


          $exploits =  $crawler->filterXPath('//table[@class="exploit_list bootstrap-wrapper"]//tr[position()=14]/
                                             td[@class="description"]/a[@href]')->each(function ($nodes) {
                     return  $nodes->text();
                         });


          foreach ($exploits as $exploit){

            //$exploit = trim(preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $exploit));

            print "<p>".$exploit."</p>";

            if ($exploit == 'VideoCharge Express 3.16.3.04 - BOF Exploit'){

                print 'same';

            }
          else {

            print '<p>diff</p>';
            print '<p>VideoCharge Express 3.16.3.04 - BOF Exploit</p>';
            print $exploit;
          }

            $crawler2 = $client->click($crawler->selectLink($exploit)->link());



                      $code = $crawler2->filterXPath('//table[@class="exploit_list"]//tr[position()=1]/td[position()=2]/a')->each(function ($nodes) {
                     return  $nodes->text();
                         });



          print "<p>".$code[0]."</p>";

          if ($code[0] != ""){

            print "there is cve";

          }

            print 'hi';

      } 







     }

     crawler_metasploit();
?>
```

The output is "diff", apparently the string is the same than when I copy paste it directly from the website but it's not, that only happens with this specific string, I have used this function too:

```
$exploit = trim(preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $exploit));
```

but no success.

What could be happening?

Comment: The first place to look would be with your first XPath query.  If the result of the XPath is "nothing" the filterXPath function will return a DomCrawler object that contains a DomNodeList with zero items.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, it actually returns, a string that seem exactly the same as if I copy paste.

That happens only with this specific link, so the XPath query is ok, because I actually take results and can click the other links without problem. What is going on with that string¿?